# Fail2ban not sending email notifications

Tags: fail2ban

My CentOS server has postfix as MTA and it’s working.
When I type the command `mail -s "testing" <my gmail address>`, I receive the email.

However, Fail2ban is unable to send emails to my gmail address when an IP gets banned. I’m probably missing some configuration in jail.conf.

Here is part of my jail.conf file:

```
destemail = myaddress@gmail.com
sendername = fail2ban
mta = sendmail
protocol = tcp
action = %(action_mwl)s
```

---

I already tried `mta = postfix` and it didn’t work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:** I was able to make it work. None of the configuration above is correct for my fail2ban v0.8.10 and my linux CentOS 6. In fact, I removed all the lines above (garbage).

I found a pre-defined action in /etc/fail2ban/action.d/mail.conf file.
I noticed this action uses "mail -s" command which works on my server.
So, I decided to use this action in my jail.conf file as such:

```
[ssh-iptables]
enabled  = true
filter   = sshd
action   = iptables[name=SSH, port=ssh, protocol=tcp]
           mail[name=ssh, dest=my-address@gmail.com]
logpath  = /var/log/secure
maxretry = 5
```

The only thing that needs to be change to get an email from fail2ban is to add that line below “action” that starts with “mail.” Very simple and easy.

Comment: action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
           %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]

Comment: Anyone? I searched for a solution, but what I found is exactly what I'm currently using.

Comment: if you know the solution, please help. I stucked, and reasked here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651281/fail2ban-email-notification-is-not-triggering

Answer (score 2):

You should change `mta = sendmail` to:

```
mta = mail
```

Comment: I tried that and it is ***not*** working still. Pleasesee. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651281/fail2ban-email-notification-is-not-triggering

Answer (score 0):

if you want email notifications with whois i found this solution

```
[sshd]
enabled = true
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
action   = iptables-ipset-proto6[name=ssh, port=ssh, protocol=tcp, bantime=0]
       mail-whois[name=sshd, dest=my-email@something.com]
findtime = 3600
bantime  = -1
maxretry = 3
```

Comment: Where do you find this solution? Can you explain your code?

Comment: i tried with mail[name=sshd, dest=my-email@something.com] but then i got just simple notifications. Just tried with mail-whois and working

Answer (score 0):

All of the above did not work for me.

What worked for me was adding second line under action =....

to be:

```
sendmail[mailcmd='/usr/sbin/sendmail -f "<sender>" "<dest>"', dest="email@recipient.com", sender="fail2ban", sendername="Fail2Ban", name="jail_name"]
```

Note: You may do so for various jails.

Also note, that if you would like to get an email notification for ModSecurity, you can do so, by setting a Fail2Ban jail for ModSecurity, and then get the email notifications.